# What should the itemcount property in SQL Server match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, full-text-indexing

If the `itemcount` property does not exactly match the number of indexed rows is that a problem? Is there a numerical way I can ensure that I have a complete full-text-index?

update: the property `fulltextcatalogproperty('database','itemcount')` does not equal the rowcount for the indexed tables. It is off by a few thousand. Does that indicate the index is missing information, or would you expect that itemcount to not exactly match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2008`, `ItemCount` won't count records that the `FULLTEXT` index does not index (`NULL`, empty, or those containing only the word separators)

Also, when your table is changed heavily, `ItemCount` can lag and not reflect the changes to the table immediately.

This is a statistical property which only serves as a hint, not as exact value.

Comment: Do you have any details on this not being exact? That would be very helpful. :)

Comment: @Judson: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143709.aspx Actually, this depends on the `SQL Server` version.